# How to find if a web site uses HSTS

Tags: curl, https, header

I'm totally new to curl and am trying to ascertain if websites use Strict-Transport-Security.

I'm running off advice. I've been told to check against [Chrome's preloaded list](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/net/base/transport_security_state_static.json?view=markup) and to run

```
curl -D - https://www.example.com | head -n 20
```

to check for Strict-Transport-Security headers.

But the 'head' command generated an error and was unknown.

Any ideas?

ATM I'm running Win XP, will have a linux distro in a few days.

Thanks.

Answer (score 33):

That method is fine.

```
$ curl -s -D- https://paypal.com/ | grep Strict
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=14400
```

As you've noticed, some webservers just refuse to honour `HEAD` requests.  `curl` will print the headers for a `GET` request with `-v`:

```
$ curl -s -vv https://paypal.com/ 2>&1 | grep Strict
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=14400
```

The `<` means the header is one returned by the server to you.

Actual `example.com`, as in your example, won't work as it doesn't listen on `https://` at all:

```
$ curl -D- https://www.example.com
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

As the `Strict-Transport-Security` header is only honoured if it is delivered over `https://`, it's very safe to assume that any site that doesn't respond to on `https://` isn't using STS, especially as it would have no reason to do so.

Comment: Actually when you contact use `wget` and contact HSTS site over http you get: `URL transformed to HTTPS due to an HSTS policy` and you end up on https

Comment: `curl -s -D- https://paypal.com/ | grep -i Strict` works better for case-insensitivity and more reliable results

Answer (score 2):

Chrome has an HSTS check feature `chrome://net-internals#hsts`

But be aware that Chrome also likes to added entries whenever you request a site over https.

Just had chrome redirect me to https for an internal site that hasn't got a https cert. Not even listening on 443. Unsurprisingly curl did not return a Strict header. I then found chrome has an internal HSTS list. Can be cleared from chrome://net-internals#hsts excluding the global Google maintained list.

Answer (score 2):

[Expanding on the answer by @FauxFaux]

I wanted to see how my site compared to other in the industry. So, I wrote a bash `for` loop. I discovered that some sites, not only don't treat `HEAD` requests differently that `GET`, but they (Amazon and Microsoft) treat `curl` different from real browsers. So, I added some headers to my request to get real responses.

### Script

```sh
# NOTE: You can copy/paste this whole block straight into a bash shell

apex_domains=(
    paypal.com
    amazon.com
    google.com
    microsoft.com
)
curl_command=`
`"curl -svo /dev/null "`
    `"-H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) "`
        `"AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36' "`
    `"-H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif"`
        `",image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' "`
    `"-H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' "`
    `"--compressed"

for domain in "${apex_domains[@]}"; do
    for scheme in 'http' 'https'; do
        for subdomain in '' 'www.'; do
            echo -e         "\n""  ${scheme}://${subdomain}${domain}"
            echo "  $curl_command  ${scheme}://${subdomain}${domain}"
            eval   "$curl_command  ${scheme}://${subdomain}${domain}" 2>&1 | \
                tr -d '\r' | grep -i --color=always 'strict-transport-security.*';
        done
    done
done
```

### Output

The output looks better on the terminal because the grepped header is highlighted.

```
  http://paypal.com
  curl -svo /dev/null -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36' -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' --compressed  http://paypal.com

  http://www.paypal.com
  curl -svo /dev/null -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36' -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' --compressed  http://www.paypal.com

  https://paypal.com
  curl -svo /dev/null -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36' -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' --compressed  https://paypal.com
< strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains

  https://www.paypal.com
  curl -svo /dev/null -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36' -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' --compressed  https://www.paypal.com
< strict-transport-security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload

  http://amazon.com
  curl -svo /dev/null -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36' -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' --compressed  http://amazon.com

  http://www.amazon.com
  curl -svo /dev/null -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36' -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' --compressed  http://www.amazon.com

  https://amazon.com
  curl -svo /dev/null -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36' -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' --compressed  https://amazon.com

  https://www.amazon.com
  curl -svo /dev/null -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36' -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' --compressed  https://www.amazon.com
< strict-transport-security: max-age=47474747; includeSubDomains; preload

  http://google.com
  curl -svo /dev/null -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36' -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' --compressed  http://google.com

  http://www.google.com
  curl -svo /dev/null -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36' -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' --compressed  http://www.google.com

  https://google.com
  curl -svo /dev/null -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36' -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' --compressed  https://google.com

  https://www.google.com
  curl -svo /dev/null -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36' -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' --compressed  https://www.google.com
< strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000

  http://microsoft.com
  curl -svo /dev/null -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36' -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' --compressed  http://microsoft.com

  http://www.microsoft.com
  curl -svo /dev/null -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36' -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' --compressed  http://www.microsoft.com

  https://microsoft.com
  curl -svo /dev/null -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36' -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' --compressed  https://microsoft.com

  https://www.microsoft.com
  curl -svo /dev/null -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36' -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' --compressed  https://www.microsoft.com
< strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
```